# Excel VBA Sequential Numbering Of Column Based On Start And Finish Numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I have a start number(I3) and Finish number (J3).
I want to place value of I3 in column B3 then sequentially go down the column till the value of J3. I am using a button for this purpose. I have searched internet and have found bits of VBA but none seem to work out for what i am after.
I understand the auto filler function but i want to do it with VBA.

```
Sub Macro1()
startNumber = [b3].Value
endNumber = [J3].Value

For i = startNumber To endNumber
    ActiveCell.Offset(i - startNumber, 0) = i
Next i
End Sub
```

Code runs but picks cell that is selected and goes down to row 100000+..
'
Many Thanks
For any assistance.
Craig
[Image of Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GqhA.jpg)

Comment: Post the code you tried, and describe what happened when you tried it. "nothing works" doesn't make for a compelling question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
Sub Macro1()
startNumber = Cells(3, 9).Value 'cell I3, as it is your start number (as you stated)
endNumber = Cells(3, 10).Value 'cell J3

For i = startNumber To endNumber
    Cells(3, 2).Offset(i - startNumber, 0) = i
Next i
End Sub
```